# How can I have two different background colors?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing an application in Xamarin Android but I have a question and it is to know if it is possible to put two different background colors, or rather that the background color is only half of the screen: 
This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:bottom="550dp">
    <shape
      android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid
         android:color="#8A0808"/>
      <size
        android:height="60dp"
        android:width="20dp" />
      <gradient
        android:centerX="1"
        android:centerColor="#8A0808"
        android:endColor="#eb5757"
        android:startColor="#d10808"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

But this code generates a problem for me and it is that when the screen has many elements, the color that I have is lowered with the screen, that is, it is not static, To use this background I am using a grid layout. 
This is my grid layout basic:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo_personalizado"
    android:rowCount="24"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you maybe share an example of what you are trying to achieve . The description is not very clear

Comment: My suggestion would be to use an image, like a vector drawable